# serialize base class property in one derived class without serializing it in second serialize class

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, radix, derived

I am looking an issue, but i am still confuse how to tackle this.
I have base class and there are some properties.
There are two derived classes from base class.

I want to serialize base class property in one derived class but i don't want to serialize same property in second serialize class.

This is not actual code just for example purpose only.

```
public class BaseRouter
{

    private Double r;  
    private Double bch;  

    [XmlElement("BaseRouter.r")]
    public double R { get { return r; } set { r = value; } }


    }
```

First derived class

```
      public class CiscoRouter : BaseRouter
{
    private String mRID; 

    [XmlAttribute("ID", Namespace = "rdf")]
    public String MRID { get { return this.mRID; } set { mRID = value; } }
    public Router()
    {

    }
```

Second derived class

```
 public class DellRouter : BaseRouter
{
    private String mRID; 

    [XmlAttribute("ID", Namespace = "rdf")]
    public String MRID { get { return this.mRID; } set { mRID = value; } }
    public Router()
    {

    }

}
```

How can I avoid `BaseRouter.r` in `DellRouter` class and include in `CiscoRouter` serialization?

Comment: Why should you use different serialization in two derived classes? It seems to me that you broke LSP.

Answer (score 0):

Define an `abstract` method in the base class, this will be used to do serialization/initialization. In the class where you want to serialize `BaseRouter.r` serialize it in this methods implementation. In the other class, do whatever would be a logical substitute.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can implement a public ShouldSerializeR() function and override it in your DellRouter class to return false.

```
class BaseRouter
{
    ...
    public double R { get { return r; } set { r = value; } }
    public virtual bool ShouldSerializeR() { return true; }
    ...
}

class DellRouter
{
    ...
    public override bool ShouldSerializeR() { return false; }
    ...
}
```